# Google Insights API does not return ruleImpact Score in Version 5. How to get this score?

Tags: google-api

I am using google insight API to get mobile friendly score and rule impact score for required site. For older version it was returning ruleImpact score

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v2/runPagespeed?url=site_name&strategy=mobile&key=API_Key

and response look similar to below link and it returned ruleImpact score

[Response](https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/3ebbdea9a0a3fa59578d573543f5cea9)

but latest version 5

https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=site_name&strategy=mobile&key=API_Key
does not return ruleImpact score for problem type.

How I can get the ruleImpact for each Problem Type in version 5 like below.

```
 "PrioritizeVisibleContent": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Prioritize visible content",
    "ruleImpact": 0,
    "groups": [
     "SPEED"
    ],
    "summary": {
     "format": "You have the above-the-fold content properly prioritized. Learn more about {{BEGIN_LINK}}prioritizing visible content{{END_LINK}}.",
     "args": [
      {
       "type": "HYPERLINK",
       "key": "LINK",
       "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/PrioritizeVisibleContent"
      }
     ]https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/3ebbdea9a0a3fa59578d573543f5cea9
    }
   },
   "SizeContentToViewport": {
    "localizedRuleName": "Size content to viewport",
    "ruleImpact": 0,
    "groups": [
     "USABILITY"
    ],
    "summary": {
     "format": "The contents of your page fit within the viewport. Learn more about {{BEGIN_LINK}}sizing content to the viewport{{END_LINK}}.",
     "args": [
      {
       "type": "HYPERLINK",
       "key": "LINK",
       "value": "https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/SizeContentToViewport"
      }
     ]
    }
   },
```

Any help would be highly appreciated?

Comment: If you compare the [v4 docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v4/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed) and the [v5 docs](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/v5/reference/pagespeedapi/runpagespeed) then it looks like the output has changed completely. I don't think that score is available anymore.

Comment: But there should be an alternative SizeContentToViewport in new version.